# Error Message in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

This is my JSP code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ page import="com.lowagie.text.DocumentException" %>
 <%@ page import="org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer" %>
 <%@ page import="java.io.FileNotFoundException" %>
 <%@ page import="java.io.FileOutputStream" %>
 <%@ page import="java.io.IOException" %>
 <%@ page import="java.io.File" %>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%

final ITextRenderer iTextRenderer = new ITextRenderer();
iTextRenderer.setDocument("http://localhost:8080/MyApp/test.jsp");
iTextRenderer.layout();
final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =new FileOutputStream(new File("invoice.pdf"));
iTextRenderer.createPDF(fileOutputStream);
fileOutputStream.close();
%>

</body>
</html>
```

When I  run this , I get **error ..**.

Here is the complete stack trace...

```
org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRRuntimeException: Could not instantiate any SAX 2 parser, including JDK default. The name of the class to use should have been read from the org.xml.sax.driver System property, which is set to: 
    org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource.newXMLReader(XMLResource.java:153)
    org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$XMLResourceBuilder.createXMLResource(XMLResource.java:170)
    org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource.load(XMLResource.java:71)
    org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.NaiveUserAgent.getXMLResource(NaiveUserAgent.java:211)
    org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.loadDocument(ITextRenderer.java:134)
    org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocument(ITextRenderer.java:138)
    org.apache.jsp.pdftest_jsp._jspService(pdftest_jsp.java:78)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

How to  fix the error ?

Comment: Please post the _complete_ stack trace, without reformatting it or removing anything.

Comment: complete stack trace updated in the original post. How to resolve now ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. is your issue resolved now ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the error:

> XRRuntimeException: Could not instantiate any SAX 2 parser, including
>   JDK default. The name of the class to use should have been read from
>   the org.xml.sax.driver System property, which is set to:

The solution is to define org.xml.sax.driver.  For example, download Xerces and set this JVM option in Tomcat (or whatever you're using):

`-Dorg.xml.sax.driver=org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser`

More details here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipsaxp/

Comment: I am having the same issue and implemented this solution but facing the same issue.

Comment: Please verify you have a Xerces .jar, and it's correctly deployed to your J2EE container.  For example: Tomcat 5.5:  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html#XML%20Parsers%20and%20J2SE%201.4, Tomcat 6++: http://blog.seba3y.com/2007/06/tomcat-6-and-endorsed-dirs.html#c8486671050922196221

Comment: Ya.I have Xerces.jar in my jboss server.